How can I get ssh agent (or similar) to work for a git signing key?
My setup works perfectly fine for the authentication ssh key:
Host github.com                                                                                                                                                                                         
    User git                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Hostname github.com                                                                                                                                                                             
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git                                                                                                                                                                         
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git-sign                                                                                                                                                                    

But the git-sign key is not added to the agent so every time I do a commit I have to type my password. I've tried experimenting with adding it outside of the Host structure, in Host *, etc. but no luck. Even adding it manually with ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/git-sign doesn't seem to work. I feel like it used to for a short while, but maybe I'm misremembering.
Is there any way I can get the same ssh agent experience with signing keys as I do with authentication keys?

The Host stanza in ~/.ssh/config configures connections, but a commit does not initiate a connection. Does ssh-add -L list the signing key?

@JimRedmond yes, it does. I'm guessing the IDE has a different instance or something though? I'm not sure.

Some IDEs do, some don't, but you never mentioned any IDE in your original question.

Ok, but I'm still stuck with a setup where for every single tab in my console and for every IDE I get constantly asked for this password unless I specifically load that key in that specific tab of that console (and I seemingly can't get it to work for IntelliJ at all). Is there no equivalent way of storing this to the ssh config?
